# Related Question Misses - with GTKX, GTK+X

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm not sure if any tweaks can be made to the algorithm that produces the `Related` questions list on SO, but I found it odd that when [**GTK3 window transparent**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994927/gtk3-window-transparent) question was asked, [**How to make a gtkwindow background transparent on linux?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832581/how-to-make-a-gtkwindow-background-transparent-on-linux) was completely missed as being related.

A cursory look at the titles suggest that the `GTK3` and the `gtkwindow` were not somehow close enough in comparison rank to warrant the questions being flagged as related (I don't know if that is in fact the case, but that was the impression). Given the number of *GTK*something questions and there not being much consistency in whether it is (e.g. `GTK2`, `GTK+2`, `gtkfoo`), maybe an extra tweak that looks for `gtk` in the title (along with the other key words, e.g. *transparent*) and bumps those questions up for the `Related` determination may be worth while.

I know this isn't high priority, but I saw it, so I thought I would pass it along to the powers that be on Meta to consider rather than just ignoring an opportunity for improvement.